# index not found exception in laravel elastic search using scout package

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

i have installed [tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic](https://github.com/ErickTamayo/laravel-scout-elastic) package of laravel and i did import my products table records but whenever i search anything then i am getting "index not found exception". below is my configuration of **scout.php** file

```
`'elasticsearch' => [

    'index' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX', 'marketplace'),

    'hosts' => [
        env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST', 'http://localhost:9200'),
    ],
],`
```

when i did `curl 'localhost:9200/marketplace/_mapping?pretty'`, then i got the following response.

```
`{

  "error" : {

"root_cause" : [ {

  "type" : "index_not_found_exception",

  "reason" : "no such index",

  "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",

  "resource.id" : "marketplace",

  "index" : "marketplace"

} ],

"type" : "index_not_found_exception",

"reason" : "no such index",

"resource.type" : "index_or_alias",

"resource.id" : "marketplace",

"index" : "marketplace"

  },

  "status" : 404

}`
```

Am i missing something in there? any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

have you added your index with PUT method by URL http://localhost:9200/marketplace ? (using cli. curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/some_index')